# Can't get web api attribute routing to work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Trying to call this method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("teacher/{teacherId}/student")]
    public IEnumerable<StudentDTO> GetByStudentByTeach(int id)
    {
```

web api config:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I run the service and call it in broswer: 
    http://localhost:17305/api/teacher/164/student

in the browser it returns a 404.  I tried in fiddler and it returns a 401.  I'm guessing the 401 is the actual issue, but would that mean the route is working and there is some other issue?  I am using windows auth.

EDIT: not, I can do call the Get method to return a list of teacher, with the usual api/teacher.  So I am able to return data, I just cant get to this custom method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the /api/ so try http://localhost:17305/teacher/164/student

api/ is define in the maphttproute, but in your route attribute is not present.

Also, change the param name of your method:  GetByStudentByTeach(int teacherId)

Comment: I removed it and the browser response changed to: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:17305/teacher/164/student'.
</Message>"

Comment: Also, change the name of the param, GetByStudentByTeach(int teacherId)

Comment: That worked! So the trick was, the parameter in the route attribute, and the method parameter have to have matching names.  Thanks!!